# python terminate/kill subprocess group

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, kill, kill-process

I have a few python scripts who are opening themselves in cascade by subprocess.Popen().

(I call script1.py who make a popen of script2.py who makes popen of script3.py, etc)

Is there any way to terminate/kill all subprocesses of script1.py from the script1.py PID.

os.killpg() doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using script2Proc = subprocess.Popen("python script2.py") and to kill it, script2Proc.kill()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the gid at the beginning of the execution of script2.py, the sub sequent processes belongs to script2 gid. So calling killpg() from script1.py with script2's pid does it well.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? Thanks

Comment: subprocess.Popen has a extremely useful argument preexec_fn, that I happily found out. By script2PID=subprocess.Popen(["script2.py"], shell=False, pre exec_fn=os.setpgrp) with os.setpgrp, that will make of my second script the leader of all subsequent processes, i.e. change his GID that subsequent forks will inherit. In this way I will be able to kill the script2 processes group by os.killpg(script2PID)

Answer (score 0):

In script1.py ,kill the subprocess which opens to script2.py.

```
Popen.terminate()
```

or
    Popen.kill()